# how to throw an exception that is not catched as an exception

Tags: c#, try-catch

Simple, I have `catch(Exception e)` everywhere in my code.
However, I would like to have a type which wouldn't be caught by this catch..

I looked up all the types and try most of them and they seem to all be caught... SystemException, etc.

How could I throw an error that skip this catch?

Comment: Catch more specific exceptions, it's a good habit to get into...

Comment: what I though, but there is already too much code... would there be a bypass, cause I don't have access to all the catches, so I cannot change them.

Comment: Consider opening a question describing the problem you are actually trying to solve.  There's probably a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# 6.0 you can define exception filters which would allow you to do what you want, although if you are needing to do this, you probably need to address the real source of the issue.

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (Exception ex) if (ex.GetType() != typeof(YourExceptionToIgnore))
{
   ...
}
```

FYI, catching an exception of type `Exception` is advised against in the framework guidelines - as mentioned elsewhere in this post, you should be only catching the specific exception types you expect to be raised.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. However,  you can code in such a way that the catch block does nothing or you can place things that have to happen into the finally block

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have a type which wouldn't be caught by this catch

Catch the more specific "type" you want before the `catch(Exception e)`. That way, you could specifically handle the more specific "type" of `Exception`

Answer (score 0):

As others suggesting you should only catch specific type exception as recommended practice. Though you can use exception filters which are available in latest version of C# 6.

```
try
{
// Some exception
}
catch (Exception e) if (e.Getype() != typeof(YourCustomException))
{
// handle exception except of type YourCustomException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try an empty `catch`, or a `switch-case` within your `catch`.